# How to run (not install) .apk file in android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have downloaded flash apk from internet and installed correctly in emulator but I think it is not running.

I can see it in **setting > application > manage application > flash** 
but are not able to see in the main screen where all applications are existing.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Is it different from installing that application on a phone ? It would not show on the "main screen" with all the other applications if it does not have the [intent](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html#ccases) for it...

What you can do is to unzip the apk file then you can you [AXMLPrinter2](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=514412) to read what intents are available in the manifest file.

Comment: i dont understand what thing exactly trying to say. please elaborate

Comment: what I am trying to say is that an installed application may not have anything to show in the application screen and what I described is the way to find whether that is the case and how to use that application.

Comment: it s downloadable app from internet. still not get properly

Comment: hmm, that does not mean anything to me... can you give a link or something ?